# AWS EventBridge Exception Cross Account Event Put

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have a lambda defined in say, account A which is sending events to an EventBridge in say, account B. Below is the code that I use to push data (put_events) using Python boto3 client.

```
        rlogger.info("Trying to send events with boto3 client " + str(json_string))
        try:
            response = client.put_events(
                Entries=[
                    {
                        'Time': str(datetime.datetime.utcnow()),
                        'Source': 'notifications-test',
                        'DetailType': 'EVENT_SAMPLE',
                        'Detail': str(json_string),
                        'EventBusName': str(event_metadata["destination"])
                    },
                ]
            )
```

The `destination` is an ARN of the event bridge in account B. I get the following client side error when I try to run the lambda.

```
2022-02-10 18:29:34,391 [MainThread  ] [ERROR]  Error sending records to event-bridge.An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutEvents operation: Cross-region api call is not allowed.
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEvents-CrossAccountEventDelivery.html

Comment: @Riz I checked my settings and it matches everything they've mentioned in the documentation. It still isn't getting delivered to the bridge from lambda.

Comment: Instead of lambda, have you tried it manually? getting the same error? It's most certainly an issue of missing permissions/policies. You need to doublecheck all the permissions.

Comment: It was most likely a policy that was missing. Also, might be something to do with cross region put_events.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the region of your eventbridge client is the same as the region of the target event bus

```py
client = boto3.client('events', region_name="<same region as defined in target ARN>")
```

Comment: Could you explain(share documentation link) why can't we put events to a cross-region event bus from lambda? Why lambda need to be in same region as event bus?

Comment: the lambda itself doesnt need to be in the same region, just the botocore/boto3 client.

Comment: But why client need to be in the same region? Can't we do cross region? I mean create the client for us-east-2 and try to put-events on us-east-1 event bus.